# How can hackers abuse javascript's eval() for cross-site attacks?

Tags: javascript, cross-site

I am setting up a website that lets users solve coding puzzles/assignments. I have a reactJS component set up so that it accepts user inputted javascript and it seems to work. However, I have read the following:

"Eval makes hacking easier. Injection hacks can be a problem, particularly with cross-site attacks)."

Just to be clear: I am evalling the inserted JS clientside, to ensure that no code can mess with my server.

So how then can a user cause any harm? What's there to 'hack'? if a user is only executing JS clientside then any malicious actions will be executed in the context of his or her pc and browser window right? And that person is able to do that in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If an attacker can send a link to another person, then the attacker can harm another person.

Comment: *I am evalling the inserted JS clientside, to ensure that no code can mess with my server.* And what if that evaluation makes a call to a server?

Comment: It can be relevant if there are sessions. For Example if the user is logged in. Imagine you could inject JS through eval() in a facebook - account. You could post images in his name / delete posts and so on.

Comment: Some [other examples here](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Direct_Dynamic_Code_Evaluation_Eval%20Injection).

Comment: @ScottMarcus a user has access to the console regardless of any usage of eval() right? So what's the difference?

Comment: @PaulT. thanks for your reply. Its pretty clear how this can cause harm in a server side language context like PHP : ) My answer was directed specifically at JS situations

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda how so? So suppose a user is logged into my system and I am using let's say NodeJS and passportJS. I now have a session monitored by my server.
Any code that is being executed is only relevant in the context of the hacker's browser? So he can mess up his own facebook profile if he is logged in? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @ScottMarcus also, let's say a hacker sends over a malicious script to the server because he figures my routes out through the network tab: what then? The only scenario in which this will lead to harm that I can think of is when I would choose to execute any user inputted strings in my serverside HTTP request handling, right?

Comment: @WAINGRO there are multiple approaches for a hacker to get into the browser context of his victim. One posibility is cross - site - scripting through url params. Lets say you are `eval()`ing a Url param. The only step the victim has to do is to open a manipulated link of the hacker. And thats a bad think that it's that easy to "hack" a users profile. See: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Code_Injection

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that any code processed by the client originates from the client in the form on strings entered into `input` fields and that may not be the case.

The primary reason why `eval()` and `innerHTML` are security risks is because the strings that you pass to them may be sent to the client from a non-verified source.

Of course, if you are going to always be the one providing the input string to `eval()` then there is (one would think) no danger, but all JavaScript code in a web page is client-side code and that client-side code is always part of an HTTP Request/Response conversation. It's the response that we're concerned about here.